# Sheets - Conditional formatting based on cell (date) in column based on dates in another column

Tags: date, google-sheets, rows, gs-conditional-formatting

New to sheets so would appreciate any assistance, unable to find appropriate guidance so far online.

I want to conditional format cells in one column based on the dates in another - and repeat the conditional formatting down all rows. 
I.E

```
Column A            Column B              Column C  
Date submitted      Target                Actual   
10/10/16            10/17/16(Col.A+7)     10/15/16
```

I want to format column B (target date) based on content of column C (actual date). If actual date is:

- on or before target - conditional format cell green,
- after target date - conditional format cell red.
- blank - no conditional format

I then want to ensure the same rule applies to all rows individually, without the condition being driven from the first row. Each row will be separate non-related items for date tracking.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do not necessarily even need column C then.

Go into conditional formatting and set the following rules:

Rule1

- **Range** B2:B
- **Format cells if...** less than or equal to
- **Value or formula** =TODAY()
- B column cells will be formated in that color if they are less than the current date

Rule2

- **Range** B2:B
- **Format cells if...** greater than
- **Value or formula** =TODAY()
- B column cells will be formated in that color if they are after the current date

If a cell is empty it will not be formatted as Google Spreadsheets will specifically look for valid values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Different interpretation:

Clear any conditional formatting from ColumnB and select B2: Format, Conditional formatting..., set `Apply to range` from B2: to something like B999 (`B2:B999`), 
Format cells if... `Custom formula is` and

```
=and(C2<>"",B2>=C2)
```

with green fill. Add another rule (same range) with `Custom formula is` and

```
=C2>B2
```

with red fill and <kbd>Done</kbd>.